# Writing a Craps Program

Tags: visual-c++

Hey Folks I am having trouble getting this program do work. I have edited the program to what i have done so far most stuff works however when i choose to dont pass which is option 2 i lose the games and it doesnt display the dice. any suggestions on how to make it work and any tips on making my program display more nicely would be appreciated

```
/*************
Program:
Author:
Description:
Last Modified:
**************/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

void getBet(int pot, int& b);
char menu();
bool playGame();
int diceRoll();
void displayDice(int dice);
void rules();
bool winner(int pass, int dontPass);


int main()
{
// Declare variables below here
char choice;
char pick = ' ';
int d1 = 0, d2 = 0, total, bet, pass, dontPass;
int pot = 100;

bool winner;

srand(time(NULL));

cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);

choice = menu();

while (choice != 'q' || choice != 'Q')
{
    if (choice == 'r' || choice == 'R')
    {
        rules();
        choice = menu();
    }

    if (choice == 'q' || choice == 'Q')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (choice == 'p' || choice == 'P')
    {
        // Begin your algorithm here

        getBet(pot, bet);

        while (bet > 0)
        {

            do
            {

                {
                    playGame();
                }
            } while (choice == 'q' || choice == 'Q');

            if (winner = false)
            {
                cout << "You win!\n\n";
                pot += bet;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You lose!\n\n";
                pot -= bet;
            }

            getBet(pot, bet);


        }



    }
}
}

char menu()
{
char choice = ' ';

cout << "Welcome to Craps!!" << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter P to Play Craps!" << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter R to Read The Rules!" << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter Q to Quit the Program" << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter The Letter Of Your Choice: ";

cin >> choice;

return choice;
}

int diceRoll()
{

int d1 = 0, d2 = 0;

int total = 0;

d1 = 1 + rand() % 6;

displayDice(d1);

d2 = 1 + rand() % 6;

displayDice(d2);

total = d1 + d2;

cout << "Player rolls " << d1 << " and " << d2 << " for a total of " << total << endl;  


return total;


} 

void displayDice(int dice)
{
if (dice == 1)
{
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "-           -" << endl;
    cout << "-     *     -" << endl;
    cout << "-           -" << endl;
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
}
if (dice == 2)
{
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "-  *        -" << endl;
    cout << "-           -" << endl;
    cout << "-        *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
}
if (dice == 3)
{
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "-  *        -" << endl;
    cout << "-     *     -" << endl;
    cout << "-        *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
}
if (dice == 4)
{
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "-  *     *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-           -" << endl;
    cout << "-  *     *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
}
if (dice == 5)
{
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "-  *     *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-     *     -" << endl;
    cout << "-  *     *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
}
if (dice == 6)
{
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    cout << "-  *     *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-  *     *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-  *     *  -" << endl;
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
}

}

void getBet(int p, int& b)
{
cout << "You have $" << p << "  Enter your bet: (0 to stop) $";
cin >> b;
while (b > p || b < 0)
{
    cout << "Error: must enter a bet between 0 and " << p << "   Enter your bet: $";
    cin >> b;
}
}

bool winner(int pass, int dontPass)
{
if (pass == 1)
    return true;
else if (dontPass == 1)
    return false;

}

bool playGame()
{
int firstRoll = 0, roll = 0, dontPass = 0, pass = 0, point = 0;

bool win = false;

cout << "Welcome to Craps Would You like to Pass or Don't Pass?" << endl;
cout << "Enter 1 to Pass" << endl;
cout << "Enter 2 to Don't Pass" << endl;
cout << "What is Your choice?: ";
cin >> pass;



system("CLS");

if (pass == 1)
{
    firstRoll = diceRoll();

    if (firstRoll == 7 || firstRoll == 11)
    {
        cout << "Pass Wins You Rolled A:" << firstRoll << endl;
        pass = true;
        return pass;
    }
    else if (firstRoll == 2 || firstRoll == 3 || firstRoll == 12)
    {
        cout << "Pass Loses You Rolled A:" << firstRoll << endl;
        dontPass = false;
        return false;
    }


    while (win == false)
    {
        system("PAUSE");

        system("CLS");

        point = firstRoll;
        cout << "Point Is : " << point << endl;
        roll = diceRoll();



        if (roll == point)
        {
            cout << "Pass Wins!! You Rolled A:" << point << endl;
            pass = true;
            return pass;
        }

        else if (roll == 7)
        {
            cout << "Pass Loses!! You Rolled A:" << point << endl;
            dontPass = false;
            return false;
        }

    }
    if (pass == 2)
    {
        firstRoll = diceRoll();

        if (firstRoll == 7 || firstRoll == 11)
        {
            cout << "DontPass Loses You Rolled A:" << firstRoll << endl;
            dontPass = false;
            return false;
        }
        else if (firstRoll == 2 || firstRoll == 3 || firstRoll == 12)
        {
            cout << "DontPass Wins You Rolled A:" << firstRoll << endl;
            pass = true;
            return pass;
        }


        while (win == false)
        {
            system("PAUSE");

            system("CLS");
            point = firstRoll;
            cout << "Point Is : " << point << endl;
            roll = diceRoll();

            if (roll == point)
            {
                cout << "DontPass Loses!! You Rolled A:" << point << endl;
                dontPass = false;
                return false;
            }

            else if (roll == 7)
            {
                cout << "DontPass Wins!! You Rolled A:" << point << endl;
                pass = true;
                return pass;
            }
        }

    }


}
}


void rules()
{
system("CLS");

cout << "Simplified Rules of Craps  Craps is played with a set of 2 dice." << endl;
cout << "\nThere are 2 outcomes(or 'lines') to a round : pass or don't pass." << endl;
cout << "\nThe first roll of a round is called the 'Come Out' roll." << endl;
cout << "\nOn the come out roll, if the roll is a 7 or 11, the pass line wins." << endl;
cout << "\nIf the come out roll is a 2, 3, or 12, the don't pass line wins (this is called 'Craps')." << endl;
cout << "\nIf none of the numbers above are rolled, then whatever was rolled is now called the 'point', and the round enters the point phase." << endl;
cout << "\nRolls continue until either the point is rolled(pass), or a 7 is rolled(don't pass)." << endl;

system("PAUSE");

system("CLS");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code has some syntax errors and some logical errors.

Please do the followings to fix it.

1. Remove the semicolon (;) after first while,

   while (choice != 'q' || choice != 'Q')
2. Close the main function : add a '}' before char menu() function.
3. Declare char choice; in menu() function.
4. Convert all the while loops to if statements in displayDice(int dice) function.

Thanks !!!

Comment: THanks I edited it and it now displays the rules but thats it no matter what option i choose.

Comment: Please debug the program and try to find out the causes. Without debugging it's hard to discover the faults.

Comment: I have made a lot of changes and the program runs just not exactly how i want it. Sorry im not very good at interpreting the debug. i have edited the program and changed what im looking for to fix.